# Flutter - How to use ellipsis for widgets in Wrap?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, flutter-layout, android-chips

I want an ellipsis to appear when the widget exceeds two lines. (not text)

Now the status is like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1e1mg.png)

I wish it was like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6m2cz.png)

this is my code

```
Wrap(
                    spacing: -1,
                    children: hashTagList
                        .map((element) => Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:8,right:4),
                      child: Chip(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 8),
                        materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                            side: BorderSide(
                              color: lightFonts60,
                              width: 1,
                            )),
                        label: Text('#'+element,
                          // overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: lightFonts60,
                            fontSize: text12,
                            fontFamily: KOREAN,
                            fontWeight: semiBold,
                          ),),
                      ),
                    )).toList(),
                  )
```

Comment: please provide more details about hashTagList.

Comment: it's just a list of hashtags

Comment: pleas add code for this

Comment: If you have a solution, I'm interested!